# Relative Path URL is downloading rather than redirecting

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make one of my PHP pages redirect to another local page on my webserver.

```
<a href="quiz1.php">Quiz</a>
```

For some reason the html hyperlink using a relative path is downloading the file rather than just going to the page.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: What is the path, what is the file getting downloaded

Comment: the path is just quiz1.php , i need it to open this page in the web browser.

Comment: Please show code, otherwise we are working in the dark and just playing 20 questions

Comment: <a href="quiz1.php">Quiz</a>

Comment: Does your server have PHP configured? Do other PHP scripts run?

Comment: sorry i tried to show code but it was not showing in text box due to html tag

Comment: Little light reading for later [How to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)